# How to call some logic in Electron application from outside?

Tags: node.js, electron

I plan to write my Electron app, but I still don't have any ideas how to implement such use case - How to call some logic in Electron application from outside?

For example, there is a real application MavensMate. I can run it and leave in tray, and next from Sublime text menu I can run different logic inside MavensMate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution:

1. In Electron app start ExpressJS server (from mainProcess)
2. In ExpressJS request handler add

   ```
   win.webContents.send('superEvent', 'ping');
   ```
3. In rendererProcess add

   ```
   ipcRenderer.on('superEvent', (event, arg) => {alert('pong')});
   ```
4. Start Electon app, open ExpressJS page in Browser and you will see alert in Electron window. Profit! :)